# NodeJS - Subtract array from array, not removing all duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Title might not make much sense, but how would you do something like:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
b = [1, 2, 3];
a.subtract(b);
```

I want this to return [2, 3, 3], and not [] like the other answers for a similar question would, which only keeps the items that are not in the other array at all instead of removing only how many are in the other array.

Comment: So only remove the first occurrence of second array item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a prototype for `Array` and filter the array by checking and eliminating the found element.

```js
Array.prototype.subtract = function (array) {
    array = array.slice();
    return this.filter(function (a) {
       var p = array.indexOf(a);
       if (p === -1)  {
           return true;
       }
       array.splice(p, 1);
    });
}

var a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    b = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(a.subtract(b));
```

Faster version with a hash table:

```js
Array.prototype.subtract = function (array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a] = (hash[a] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return this.filter(function (a) {
       return !hash[a] || (hash[a]--, false);
    });
}

var a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    b = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(a.subtract(b));
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks! I was using something similar but a little different and that was removing all the duplicates instead of just once per occurence in the second array, like Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

Comment: I updated [my testbench](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46017110/1541563) with your faster version. It's still consistently slower than using `Set`

Comment: but my solution works with ES5.

Comment: @NinaScholz doesn't matter anyway, my previous answer was invalid. I've updated by improving upon the performance of your answer now, when I corrected mine and switched to use `Map`, it was actually 13% slower than your plain object approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` and `indexOf()` to check if element exists in other array and if it does delete it using `splice()`

```js
var a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
var b = [1, 2, 3];

var result = a.filter(function(e) {
  let i = b.indexOf(e)
  return i == -1 ? true : (b.splice(i, 1), false)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I was using something similar but didn't use splice to remove it, instead just removing all of it from the array (which wasn't right): Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do this: loop through the array `b` and check if it exists in the array `a`. If so, insert a `undefined` at the its index. Return the `a` array filtered to remove all `undefined` elements.

EDIT: actually no need for the filter use `splice()` has the others did.

```js
let a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
let b = [1, 2, 3];

let sub = function(a, b) {

  for (i in b) {
    let index = a.indexOf(b[i]);
    if (index != -1) {
      a.splice([index],1)
    }
  }
  
  return a

}

console.log(sub(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here that suggest the use of `indexOf()` to check for existence are inefficient O(n^2) runtime. A more efficient approach would be to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and check for existence with [`has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has), bringing the runtime down to O(n):

```js
// see the bottom of the answer for a more efficient implementation than this
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'subtract', {
  configurable: true,
  value: function subtract (array) {
    return this.filter(
      function (element) {
        const count = this.get(element)

        if (count > 0) {
          this.set(element, count - 1)
        }

        return count === 0
      }, array.reduce(
        (map, element) => {
          if (map.has(element)) {
            map.set(element, map.get(element) + 1)
          } else {
            map.set(element, 1)
          }

          return map
        }, new Map()
      )
    )
  },
  writable: true
})

let a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
let b = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(a.subtract(b))
```

Here's a testbench to show the efficiency of this solution compared to @Nina's answer:

```js
Array.prototype.ninaSubtract = function (array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a] = (hash[a] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return this.filter(function (a) {
       return !hash[a] || (hash[a]--, false);
    });
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'patrickSubtract', {
  configurable: true,
  value: function subtract (array) {
    return this.filter(
      function (element) {
        const count = this.get(element)

        if (count > 0) {
          this.set(element, count - 1)
        }

        return count === 0
      }, array.reduce(
        (map, element) => {
          if (map.has(element)) {
            map.set(element, map.get(element) + 1)
          } else {
            map.set(element, 1)
          }

          return map
        }, new Map()
      )
    )
  },
  writable: true
})

let a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
let b = [1, 2, 3]

let ninaStart = 0
let ninaStop = 0
let patrickStart = 0
let patrickStop = 0

ninaStart = performance.now()

for (let i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {
  a.ninaSubtract(b)
}

ninaStop = performance.now()

patrickStart = performance.now()

for (let i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {
  a.patrickSubtract(b)
}

patrickStop = performance.now()

console.log('Nina time: ', ninaStop - ninaStart, 'ms')
console.log('Patrick time: ', patrickStop - patrickStart, 'ms')
```

Running it several times on my laptop using Chrome v60 indicates that Nina's updated answer using a plain object is approximately 13% faster than my answer.

Let's try to beat that by improving upon her answer:

```js
Array.prototype.ninaSubtract = function (array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a] = (hash[a] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return this.filter(function (a) {
       return !hash[a] || (hash[a]--, false);
    });
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'patrickSubtract', {
  configurable: true,
  value: function subtract (array) {
    const lookup = Object.create(null)
    const output = []

    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      const element = array[index]
      lookup[element] = element in lookup ? lookup[element] + 1 : 1
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
      const element = this[index]

      if (!(element in lookup) || lookup[element]-- <= 0) {
        output.push(element)
      }
    }

    return output
  },
  writable: true
})

let a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
let b = [1, 2, 3]

let ninaStart = 0
let ninaStop = 0
let patrickStart = 0
let patrickStop = 0

ninaStart = performance.now()

for (let i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {
  a.ninaSubtract(b)
}

ninaStop = performance.now()

patrickStart = performance.now()

for (let i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {
  a.patrickSubtract(b)
}

patrickStop = performance.now()

console.log('Nina time: ', ninaStop - ninaStart, 'ms')
console.log('Patrick time: ', patrickStop - patrickStart, 'ms')
```

That is a lot more performant, though a bit less canonical since it avoids the use of `reduce()`, `forEach()` or `filter()` in order to reduce context switches from function calls. This solution executes in almost half the time of Nina's updated answer (about 43% faster):

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'subtract', {
  configurable: true,
  value: function subtract (array) {
    const lookup = Object.create(null)
    const output = []

    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      const element = array[index]
      lookup[element] = element in lookup ? lookup[element] + 1 : 1
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
      const element = this[index]

      if (!(element in lookup) || lookup[element]-- <= 0) {
        output.push(element)
      }
    }

    return output
  },
  writable: true
})

let a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
let b = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(a.subtract(b))
```

#### Update

The reason for the discrepancy in performance before was because my previous algorithm using `Set` was not correct. If `b` were to contain non-unique elements, then the output would not have been correct.